# Cannot comment because not enough points, cannot post because title similar

Tags: json

I know the command is:   delete json['element']
Everyplace I see someone saying it does not work the answer is always

```
delete json['element'] 
delete json.element
```

I have a mongodb collection called user and returns the requested object from the database.

```
var userBuffer = req.user
console.log(userBuffer)  //prints the full object
delete userBuffer['_id']
console.log(userBuffer)  //still prints the same full object with _id key and value
```

It does not matter which element I try to delete such as:

```
delete userBuffer['name']
```

I cannot set the elements to undefined because the objects for -id are not a real part of the mongodb object. Anyone have any solutions besides saying the answer is to use `delete json['element']`  ?